# how to capture text in different variables with same class name in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to capture the texts i.e.'You're not sure about' and 'Ways to get assistance'  in different variables. however when i try using this

```
$('.perind-details__summary-text').text();
```

I am getting result in same variable as "
        You're not sure about
               Ways to get assistance
      "
How to capture these two different texts in different variables?

```
<details class="perind-details" open="">
    <summary class="perind-details__summary" role="button" volu-controls="short-content-0" volu-expanded="true">
      <span class="perind-details__summary-text">
        You're not sure about
      </span>

<details class="perind-details" open="">
    <summary class="perind-details__summary" role="button" volu-controls="short-content-0" volu-expanded="true">
      <span class="perind-details__summary-text">
        Ways to get assistance
      </span>
    </summary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map` first instead:

```js
const texts = $('.perind-details__summary-text')
  .map(function() { return $(this).text().trim() })
  .get();
console.log(texts);

const [text1, text2] = texts;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details class="perind-details" open="">
    <summary class="perind-details__summary" role="button" volu-controls="short-content-0" volu-expanded="true">
      <span class="perind-details__summary-text">
        You're not sure about
      </span>

<details class="perind-details" open="">
    <summary class="perind-details__summary" role="button" volu-controls="short-content-0" volu-expanded="true">
      <span class="perind-details__summary-text">
        Ways to get assistance
      </span>
    </summary>
```

Or, no need for a big library like jQuery for something this simple:

```js
const texts = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.perind-details__summary-text'),
  elm => elm.textContent.trim()
);

console.log(texts);
```

```html
  <summary class="perind-details__summary" role="button" volu-controls="short-content-0" volu-expanded="true">
    <span class="perind-details__summary-text">
        You're not sure about
      </span>

    <details class="perind-details" open="">
      <summary class="perind-details__summary" role="button" volu-controls="short-content-0" volu-expanded="true">
        <span class="perind-details__summary-text">
        Ways to get assistance
      </span>
      </summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use id attribute to make it easier for the selector to find it.

```
<details class="perind-details" open="">
    <summary class="perind-details__summary" role="button" volu-controls="short-content-0" volu-expanded="true">
      <span id="perind-details__summary-text-1">
        You're not sure about
      </span>

<details class="perind-details" open="">
    <summary class="perind-details__summary" role="button" volu-controls="short-content-0" volu-expanded="true">
      <span id="perind-details__summary-text-2">
        Ways to get assistance
      </span>
    </summary>
```

then you use it like this to select the specific id.

```
var text1 = $('#perind-details__summary-text-1').text();
var text2 = $('#perind-details__summary-text-2').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using class in CSS. So you can't just change class to solve the issue, but why don't you add an ID to each input?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text1 = $('.perind-details__summary-text').eq(0).text();
var text2 = $('.perind-details__summary-text').eq(1).text();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22017619)

Comment: @SteakOverflow This is an [attempt to answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). It should not be deleted

Comment: I see your point. The comment is a default message that is automatically added after a review. Sorry for the confusion. The reason I marked this for delete is that it does not follow the basics of how to write a good answer. Stack Overflow has guidelines and we all make efforts to follow them so that our answer benefit the community https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

A better way if you don't want to use ID. 
Then create a variable as an array. Iterate the class node then you can push that text in the array. Later you can use that array to use pushed text wherever you want.